# Size of labels on this figure smaller than size of mathmodes. How can I repair them?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is my figure which I drawed in Geogebra.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
This is some text with $S$, $A$, $B$, $C$
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (10,7.5);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (3,3)-- (0,0);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (0,0)-- (6,0);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (6,0)-- (9,3);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (9,3)-- (3,3);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (3,3)-- (1.5,7);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (1.5,7)-- (1.5,1.5);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.5,7)-- (0,0);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.5,7)-- (9,3);
\draw [line width=1.2pt, ,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (2.25,5)-- (9,3);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (2.25,5)-- (2.25,2.25);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (2.25,2.25)-- (9,3);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.5,7)-- (6,0);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-0.13,-0.13) node {$B$};
\draw [fill=black] (3,3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (3.06,3.19) node {$A$};
\draw [fill=black] (6,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (6.08,-0.15) node {$D$};
\draw [fill=black] (9,3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (9.16,3.05) node {$C$};
\draw [fill=black] (1.5,1.5) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.55,1.34) node {$H$};
\draw [fill=black] (1.5,7) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.54,7.22) node {$S$};
\draw [fill=black] (2.25,5) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (2.3,5.28) node {$F$};
\draw [fill=black] (2.25,2.25) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (2.26,2.04) node {$G$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]
The size of labels $S$, $A$, $B$, ... in the figure is smaller than size of mathmodes $S$, $A$, $B$, ...outside the figure. How can I repair it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you have `\begin{scriptsize}`...`\end{scriptsize}` and so your letters are printed in scriptsize.

Removing it and adjusting a little the positioning of the letters should be what you want.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
This is some text with $S$, $A$, $B$, $C$
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (10,7.5);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (3,3)-- (0,0);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (0,0)-- (6,0);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (6,0)-- (9,3);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (9,3)-- (3,3);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (3,3)-- (1.5,7);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (1.5,7)-- (1.5,1.5);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.5,7)-- (0,0);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.5,7)-- (9,3);
\draw [line width=1.2pt, ,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (2.25,5)-- (9,3);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (2.25,5)-- (2.25,2.25);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (2.25,2.25)-- (9,3);
\draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.5,7)-- (6,0);
\draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-0.13,-0.25) node {$B$};
\draw [fill=black] (3,3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (3.21,3.22) node {$A$};
\draw [fill=black] (6,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (6.08,-0.25) node {$D$};
\draw [fill=black] (9,3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (9.26,3.05) node {$C$};
\draw [fill=black] (1.5,1.5) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.67,1.34) node {$H$};
\draw [fill=black] (1.5,7) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.54,7.28) node {$S$};
\draw [fill=black] (2.25,5) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (2.01,4.95) node {$F$};
\draw [fill=black] (2.25,2.25) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (2.38,2.04) node {$G$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @ karlkoeller You are right. I voted up for you.